# Unspecified ETW events - GC/Mark, GC/Triggered, GC/GenerationRange etc

Tags: .net, garbage-collection, etw, perfview

I ran perfview and looked at GC events. There is a list of events that can be found in perfview events view - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff356162(v=vs.100).aspx

My question is: where can I find the missing events like GC/Triggered, GC/Mark, ... that are not listed at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff356162(v=vs.100).aspx ? 
What is their meaning?

[image]